# How do I buffer until last stream in RxJs

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-observable

So far I can buffer using `buffer(observable)` which buffer until provided observable emit or `bufferCount(count)` which wait until certain count of streams get emitted or using `bufferTime(time)` and `bufferToggle()` all of which does not solve my case which requires to buffer until the last emission and return all emissions as an array?

Comment: So if you have `src$,pipe(buffer(notifier$))`, you'll want to receive the collected values only when `notifier$` sends its last emitted value?

Comment: @AndreiGătej correct. I wish I could create `notifier$` observable that only fire when the stream ends but I don't now how.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are looking for [`toArray`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/toarray) operator.

From their docs:

> Collects all source emissions and emits them as an array when the source completes.

Comment: The problem is `toArray` operator need to receive buffer of streams and it will convert it to array, so I will have to precede it with `take` operator to buffer the stream first but take operator need count as the parameter and in my case I need all streams regardless of the count.

Comment: @kasongoyo `toArray` doesn't receive any arguments, it just collects all the emissions into a single array and emits it when the source observable completes.

Comment: Yeah it's true. What I wanted to say is the `toArray()` will not work until the source complete so if the source is created by let's say Subject then `toArray` will not work but if the source is created by something like `of` operator then it can work because `of` observable iterate and complete the subscription immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```js
src$.pipe(
   buffer(notifier$.pipe(last(null, 'default value')))
)
```

`last()` will emit the latest emitted value when the source **completes**(ends). We're providing a default value in case the source did not emit anything, but you'd still want to get the collected values.

---

#### EDIT

if you want to buffer until the last emission of the **source**, you could try this:

```js
src$ = src$.pipe(publish(), refCount());

src$.pipe(
   buffer(src$.pipe(last()))
);
```

`publish()` + `refCount()` will make sure the source won't be subscribed multiple times, by placing a `Subject` instance between the data producer and the data consumers.

---

#### EDIT 2

Here's a concrete example:

```js
const src$ = fromEvent(document, 'click')
  .pipe(
    take(3),
    map((_, idx) => idx + 1), 
    publish(), 
    refCount(),
  );

src$.pipe(
  buffer(src$.pipe(last()))
).subscribe(console.warn); // after clicking 3 times: [1, 2, 3]
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/buffer-until-src-completes?file=index.ts).

It's important that the source(`src$`) does not emit and does not complete synchronously. If this happens, when the observable passed to `buffer` completes, the outer observable will complete as well.

Comment: Will the `last()` emit when `src` complete or when `notifier$` observable complete? What's the `notifier$`observable in that context because it seems like a new independent observable created before src?

Comment: `last()` will emit when `notifier$` completes. When `src$` completes, the complete notification will be sent do the data consumer(e.g your subscriber from `obs$.subscribe(subscriber)`).

Comment: _What's the notifier$observable ..._ hmm, I think I misunderstood your question. By `requires to buffer until the last emission`, did you mean the last emission of the **source** ? Something like: `src$.pipe(src$.pipe(last(...)))` ?

Comment: Correct. Is this `src$.pipe(src$.pipe(last(...)))` something valid?

Comment: No, I forgot about `buffer`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I have tried it here https://jsfiddle.net/kaxo/a2t058sx/1/ but it doesn't seems to work as I expected. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'd recommend using RxJS version `6.5.x`, in your example you're using an older version. The problem is that your source(`interval`) emits synchronously and then completes. And because you're using `buffer`, when its inner observable completes, the main source will complete as well. I'll provide an example in ~20 min.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle with RxJS `6.x.x` here https://jsfiddle.net/kaxo/a2t058sx/5/, incase you will write on top of my fiddle. Also, does it mean that it cannot work with synchronous sources?

Comment: @kasongoyo I've added a concrete example.